# Android: Unable to inflate EditText in the layout

Tags: android

I am trying to inflate a `EditText` view inside a `RelativeLayout` in my `Activity`.

But getting an error says:

> The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.

My code:

```
RelativeLayout relLayout= new RelativeLayout(insideActivity);
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,           RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
relLayout.setLayoutParams(params);

LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.holo_edit_text, null);
EditText searchBox = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.holo_text);

relLayout.addView(searchBox);
```

And here is holo_edit_text.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <EditText 
        android:id="@+id/holo_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:singleLine="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Exception log please.

Comment: Why do you insert it by hand? Use XML layout description. Or add inflated view directly to ther relLayout.

Comment: @user527759 My complete layout will be created dynamically in my Activity. And I cannot add a style to my Edittext programmatically. Adding a style to Edittext is possible in xml only. So I am inflating the EditText only from xml.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed my issue by simply setting the LayoutParams to searchBox before adding it to the RelativeLayout. And its working fine.

Thanks all for your response.

Answer (score 1):

your holo_edit_text.xml should be

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <EditText 
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/holo_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:singleLine="true"
     />
```

And the way you add it to the view should be like this

**EDIT** (use getLayoutInflater() instead)

```
 View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.holo_edit_text, null);
 //EditText searchBox = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.holo_text);
 //The last sentence is not neccesary
 relLayout.addView(view);
```

Have you tried this while adding to relative layout

```
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
    relLayout.addView(view, params);
```

Comment: First I have tried the same thing. And inflated it. 

EditText searchBox = inflater.inflate(R.layout.holo_edit_text, null);
relLayout.addView(searchBox);

And nothing is getting displayed.

Comment: I have already tried all these you have mentioned till now. But nothing is getting displayed.

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
View child_view = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.holo_edit_text, null);
relLayout.addView(child_view);
```

Comment: Tried it, but doesn't work. Tried getLayoutInflater() also, but no luck

Answer (score 0):

Use a try/catch mechanism.

```
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            if (rootView != null) {
                ((ViewGroup) rootView.getParent()).removeView(rootView);
            }
              try {
               rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_layout_file_here, container,false);
               EditText searchBox = (EditText)rootView.findViewById(R.id.holo_text);
               relLayout.addView(searchBox);
              } catch (InflateException e) {

              }
            return rootView;
        }
```